# Release redis connection back to pool using python

Tags: python, caching, redis

I have a job scheduled which writes data to Redis cache.
For each data set row, I fetch a connection from the pool and use redis.pipeline to insert it into Redis, but when I monitor via info clients the connected_clients number keeps on increasing, I see maxclients as 7500 but when connected_clients reach 1049, its halts and does not process further with error redis.exceptions.TimeoutError: Timeout connecting to server

[image]

I fetch the connection via the below method

```
from redis import asyncio as aioredis

def get_redis_connection(db_name: int) -> aioredis.Redis:
    redis_protocol = "rediss" if redis_settings.redis_ssl else "redis"
    return aioredis.Redis(
        auto_close_connection_pool=True,
        host=redis_settings.redis_hostname,
        port=redis_settings.redis_port,
        db=db_name,
        password=redis_settings.redis_password,
        ssl=redis_settings.redis_ssl,
        connection_pool=aioredis.ConnectionPool.from_url(
                f"{redis_protocol}://:{redis_settings.redis_password}@{redis_settings.redis_hostname}:{redis_settings.redis_port}/{db_name}",
                connection_class=aioredis.Connection,
                max_connections=redis_settings.redis_pool_size,
            ),
        health_check_interval=HEALTH_CHECK_INTERVAL,
    )
```

This is how I use the connection

```
async def populate_data_to_cache(bars: Iterator[BarsUnique]):
    grouped_bars = {}
    for bar in bars:
        key = f"{bar.code}:{bar.dir}"

        if key in grouped_bars:
            grouped_bars[key].append(encode_data(bar))
        else:
            grouped_bars[key] = [encode_data(bar)]

    async with cache.get_redis_connection(BAR_DB) as redis:
        for key in grouped_bars.keys():
            async with redis.pipeline(transaction=True) as p:
                await p.delete(key)
                await p.rpush(key, *grouped_data[key])
                await p.expire(key, timedelta(days=cache.DEFAULT_EXPIRATION_DAYS))
                await p.execute()
```

Currently, I am using Python 3.10 and redis 5.0.0